# Azure Table Storage returns null value randomly

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I'm querying my azure table, randomly azure query returns null value randomly.

I tried using continuation token as well but it did't worked for me.

```cs
var continuationToken = default(TableContinuationToken);
CloudTable cloudTable = _cloudTableClient.GetTableReference(_tableName);
var filter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition(RowKey, QueryComparisons.Equal, instanceId);
var query = new TableQuery<Container>().Where(filter);
do
{
var retrievedResult = await cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, continuationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

//comment out since it has more than 1 result returned.
//var result= retrievedResult.Results.SingleOrDefault();
continuationToken = retrievedResult.ContinuationToken;
retryCounter++;
}
while (continuationToken != null && retryCounter < 15);
```

For the above filter of row key value exists in table but randomly azure returns null.

Could you please help me on this.

Comment: can you please provide the whole code? and how do you check if it's null or not?

Comment: @IvanYang : Thanks for your response, Actually result is null when i query using row key. this is not reproducible it occurs randomly.

Comment: I see you're querying with partitionKey and rowKey in your code. if you're just using rowKey, please correct it in your post :)

Comment: @IvanYang : Updated!!! :)

Comment: How many records has the same rowkey in your table? which version of nuget package are you using?

Comment: @IvanYang: less than 1000 records. I am using SDK version WindowsAzure.Storage.Table (8.6.0) with .Net core 2.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197535/discussion-between-ivan-yang-and-er-yasar).

Comment: I'm using [WindowsAzure.Storage nuget 9.3.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/
), test 10 times, every time it returns me the correct value. And if it's a console project, please add Console.ReadLine(); at the end of the code.